# Best approach for learning Reinforcement Learning coming from economics?

Tags: machine-learning, references, reinforcement-learning

I have an economics background so I have have Calculus, Linear Algebra, Diff. Eq., 2 semesters of Stats and Prob. and some Python Knowledge.

My school offers a 2 months postgraduate course in Reinforcement Learning that follow Sutton and Barto Reinforcement Learning Introduction book.

I read a couple pages and I´m not sure if I'd be able to follow with my background. I would like to - at least - get the applications and pass the course (which requires exercises and a final application project or exposing a topic based on the latest papers).

Do you think it'd be doable or I am aiming to high? Any recommendation if you think I'm there or close? 
I don't want to enroll and loose time and money if I'm not ready yet.